# Generalizations of Cauchy's root test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

There are some convergence tests that involve applying certain functions or transformations on the generic term of a series in order to determine if it converges, and then taking a limit.

$$\lim_{k → ∞} \sqrt[k]{a_k}<1 \qquad \text{"root test"}$$
$$\lim_{k → ∞} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} < 1\qquad \text{"ratio test"}$$

In general, proving these convergence tests is somewhat similar and involves some sort of inverse operation (e.g. exponentiation in the case of the root test and multiplication in the case of the ratio test), and using the comparison test, along with a series that is related to the inverse operation.

Is there a generalization of some sort that allows one to apply similar transformations in order to determine convergence?

Comment: This is one area where Wikipedia does a good job. Check out the Convergent Series value for a comprehensive list of standard tests and known counterexamples.

Comment: I've looked through it and searched, but I haven't found what I was looking for.

Comment: @user142526 Wikipedia lists a bunch of tests, but it doesn't describe a unifying general framework from which similar tests may be derived.

Comment: The thing is, rather than being two examples of an underlying proposition, these two known tests are just different ways of comparing the rate of decay of a series' elements with exponential decay. In both cases, weaker forms of decay (whether or not they yield a convergent series) will fail the test. In any event, I'm unaware of any such unifying approach.